# How to type two characters on top of each other (superscript) in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

In astronomical publications that use proper typesetting, the magnitude of an object is written like this:

[image: magnitude of objects]

The `m` has the same x position as the comma.

How is this done in Indesign CC2014? I'm new to typesetting and I have no idea how to google this. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: If it's an astronomical publication, they undoubtedly used [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) to generate the document. The command for that would be `5\overset{\rm m}{,}6/6\overset{\rm m}{,}5` as you can verify [here](http://arachnoid.com/latex/). See also [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have to work with the letter `m`.

Select the letter `m` and in the character formatting controls make the following:

- make the letter `m` **[superscript]** or
- reduce the **[font size]** of that m, and increase the **[baseline shift]** to an appropriate value.
- still `m` selected. reduce **[Tracking]** to any value you like.
- after you finish save the selected `m` in a **[character style]** to repeat it so and so.

Comment: Works perfectly as you described, thanks!  
Here's what I did.  
  
- Selected m  
  
- reduced the **[font size]** of that m  
  
- increased the **[baseline shift]**  
  
- reduced **[tracking]**  
  
now the fractional part was too close to the m  
  
- added a space after the comma  
  
- reduced **[tracking]** for that space  
  
and finally fine tuned the m  
  
- tuned the **[baseline shift]** of m  
  
- tuned the **[font size]** of m  
  
Thank you!

PS Actually it was easier than trying to get this very comment formatted properly.

Comment: There are some fonts over the internet for scientific equations. The superscript m could be stored in the font with 0 tracking.

Comment: I was going to phrase it as "kern the bejabbers out of that sucker," but hsawires said it much more elegantly.